# How to update or insert a line after a pattern has been matched

Tags: awk, sed

I basically need an `awk` or `sed` one liner to insert or edit/replace `gateway x.x.x.x` to `/etc/network/interfaces` file for specific IF device (it can be em1 or p2p1 or p3p1). I'm using ubuntu linux.

It should be better not use constant line number based regex code, like replace/insert 3rd line after `auto em1`.

Notice, the parameter may change as `auto p2p1` or `auto p3p1`.

Scenario 1: gateway not exist for em1, insert new one

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
address 192.168.2.98
netmask 255.255.255.0
something random       <-- gateway x.x.x.x should be inserted before or after this for em1
auto p2p1
iface p2p1 inet static
address 192.168.2.121
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
auto p3p1
iface p3p1 inet static
address 192.168.2.121
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
```

Scenario 2: Edit/Replace

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
address 192.168.2.98
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway x.x.x.x       <-- should only edit or replace this one (when em1 requested)
auto p2p1
iface p2p1 inet static
address 192.168.2.121
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1   <-- not this one (when em1 requested)
auto p3p1
iface p3p1 inet static
address 192.168.2.121
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1   <-- or this one (when em1 requested)
```

Thanks.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Believe me I tried, this is last resort. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @thekamilz, elaborate this `should only edit or replace this one for em1` action on a concrete test case

Comment: Ok I think I made it clear, if em1 given on one liner with say `auto em1` then it should do as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`, you should have a well-defined pattern that separates the interfaces. In your case, I assume that all of them start with "auto", so this string will be the pattern to use. In case you need a different one, depending on your data, the logic below remains the same.

```
awk -v i="em1" -v g="192.168.1.42" '
    f && /^auto/    {print "gateway "g; f=0}
    f && /^gateway/ {print "gateway "g; f=0; next}
    $0 ~ "auto "i   {f=1}
                    {print}
    END             {if (f) print "gateway "g}
' file
```

You see that the difference is that `next`. When updating, we call `next` and don't reach the last `print` action for this line (which is the old gateway)
When inserting, we don't call it, so we print the line (which is the start of a new inteface)

Added a final `END {}` statement to print the gateway line if `EOF` is reached and still `f=1`. This is to fix the case when we edit the last interface and no gateway already exists.

Comment: Awesome work! thank you very much, I'll use this code, just a little problem if you can fix that too it's really appreciated, otherwise I'll use this code anyway. Problem is the last IF device entry (p3p1 in this case) if there is no gateway x.x.x.x for this device, this code doesn't work. I did manually delete very last line which is gateway 192.168.2.1 and noticed this. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh yes, that's important. Because EOF found while still f=1. I will update answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Really appreciated. Tested, works OK.